# Using tablet as a computer draw pad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, tablet, drawing

I want to be able to take, say my iPad mini, and be able to use it to draw on my computer. I don't care about graphics and all that fancy stuff, I just want the tablet to basically be a really fancy mouse. I don't need to see the screen from my tablet's screen, I just need to be able to interface with many  I am hoping it is Windows and Linux (Ubuntu Deskop) compatible as well.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I was able to find 2 examples of mobile apps that can be used as remote input devices for computers: [Remote Mouse](http://www.remotemouse.net/) and [Mobile Mouse Remote](http://www.mobilemouse.com/).  The mobile apps installs on your mobile device to work as the controller and also has a corresponding server app that needs to be installed on the computer to-be-remote-controlled.  Remote Mouse supports iOS and Android on the mobile side and MacOS, Windows, and Linux on the server side.  Mobile Mouse remote supports iOS and Android on the mobile side and MacOS and Windows on the server side.